# Xubuntu 13.10 position of remote cursor (teamviewer, x11vnc) does not change

Tags: xubuntu, vnc, teamviewer

I am using Xubuntu 13.10 and want to remotely access this machine. Everything works fine except that the mouse courser position doesn't change on the remote system if I move it on the server machine (Xubuntu 13.10). Its shape is updating if I accidentally hover the mouse pointer over a textfield or anything else but the position is fixed. I have tested `Teamviewer` (yes I've checked "show remote cursor" on the client) and `x11vnc` (tested various cursor options). Both behave similar: The cursor shape updates but the position is fixed. I have tested XFCE, LXDE with Openbox and KDE. Its the same on all desktops environments

Comment: I have tested XFCE, LXDE with Openbox and KDE. Its the same on all desktops environments

Comment: Please include this info in the the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I am using xrdp directly connecting using windows remote desktop

```
apt-get install xrdp -y
chkconfig --levels 35 xrdp on
service xrdp start
```

Once installed on destination, connect with remote desktop using

```
Module: sesman-Xvnc
username: your username (not the name of your account shown on login desktop, use your UserName)
password: your password
```

Comment: How do I tell xrdp to take the current xsession I am using on the host?

Comment: OK, I used [this](http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/Xrdp,_installing#vino_for_.22active_session.22_remote_login) but still no remote cursor

Comment: Vino had problems with the screen resolution (it was 1366x768, which is not a multiple of 4). After changing it to 1360x768 the cursor is shown!

Comment: Why do you use `yum` on an Ubuntu-based distro?

Comment: Sorry, I had several operating systems on my house. For servers I use CentOS, for desktops & notebooks I am using Ubuntu. Thanks for the reminder. I updated the post.